Updating Quarkus Version 2 to 3 works locally but throws RuntimeException in Kubernetes pod with IllegalAccessError
I'm experiencing an issue with my Quarkus 3 application when I update from Quarkus 2. It builds and runs successfully on my local machine, but when deployed to a Kubernetes pod I get a RuntimeException. I only get this error after I updated to quarkus 3. With quarkus 2 the deployment still works and quarkus runs on the kubernetes pod. It fails with the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.doRun(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:61)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.main(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:70)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:44)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:124)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class jakarta.validation.Validation$ProviderSpecificBootstrapImpl tried to access private method 'void jakarta.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.<init>()' (jakarta.validation.Validation$ProviderSpecificBootstrapImpl and jakarta.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl are in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.RunnerClassLoader @73c6c3b2), (Type jakarta.validation.Validation$ProviderSpecificBootstrapImpl (loader: io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.RunnerClassLoader @73c6c3b2) is not a nest member of type jakarta.validation.Validation (loader: io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.RunnerClassLoader @73c6c3b2): current type is not listed as a nest member, Type jakarta.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl (loader: io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.RunnerClassLoader @73c6c3b2) is not a nest member of type jakarta.validation.Validation (loader: io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.RunnerClassLoader @73c6c3b2): current type is not listed as a nest member)
    at jakarta.validation.Validation$ProviderSpecificBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:209)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.HibernateValidatorRecorder$2.created(HibernateValidatorRecorder.java:64)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.initBeanContainer(ArcRecorder.java:79)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ArcProcessor$generateResources844392269.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ArcProcessor$generateResources844392269.deploy(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more

Here is some information of my pom.xml:
<properties>
    <jakarta.jakartaee-api.version>10.0.0</jakarta.jakartaee-api.version>
    <jakarta.resource-api.version>2.1.0</jakarta.resource-api.version>
    <jakarta.ws.rs-api.version>3.1.0</jakarta.ws.rs-api.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>3.1.0.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>all</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.resource</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.resource-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakarta.resource-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jakarta.jakartaee-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jakarta.ws.rs-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

The application builds and runs without issues on my local machine. The error only occurs when running in a Kubernetes pod.
The Dockerfile.jvm in my quarkus project contains the following image:
registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/openjdk-17:1.20.
I use gitlab and a gitlab-ci.yml to build the docker image via the image buildah/buildah:
buildah bud --format docker -f src/main/docker/Dockerfile.jvm.
I'm using the latest version of Quarkus 3.1.0.Final as you can see in my pom.xml.
I've tried the following troubleshooting steps:

Verified that all dependencies have matching versions (no version conflicts are detected by intellij). I have both jakarta.validation-api and quarkus-hibernate-validator dependencies with matching versions.
Performed a clean build and redeployment.

Since I'm new to the Kubernetes world, I don't know what could be causing this discrepancy between local and pod environments, and how can I resolve this IllegalAccessError?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Please let me know if I need to provide more information because I don't know what other information could be crucial to solve this problem.

I simply took out the jakarta.jakartaee-api dependency. It then didn't have this error anymore. Seemed like there were conflicts which we could neither resolve nor detect locally.
